# get many #hash values in url (anchor) in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, hash, anchor

i try to get values of a url with anchor like this: `http://website/list/#/genre/song`

It is in jquery because after i get the values, i have to edit html tags contents.

I retrieve hash value with:

```
 var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1);
```

I have 2 variables:

```
var genre;
var song;
```

the problem is that there may be 2 possibilities in the url:

1. `http://website/list/#/genre` or `http://website/list/#/genre/`

or

2. `http://website/list/#/genre/song` or `http://website/list/#/genre/song/`

if we are in case 1, i would have 'genre' value from hash variable

if we are in case 2, i would have 'genre' and 'song' values from hash variable

my jquery function is actually simple:

```
$(function(){
  var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1);
  var url_parts = hash.replace(/\/\s*$/,'').split('/');
  console.log("result: "+url_parts);
 });
```

I do not know how to consider the two cases. Actually i just get a full string.

And if i try `http://website/list/#/genre/`, the result is:

```
result: ,genre
```

can you help me?

Comment: w/`var parts=location.hash.split("/").filter(String)`; parts[0]=genre and parts[1]=song (if any)

Comment: with  http://website/list/#/genre/song

`     var parts=location.hash.split("/").filter(String);
      console.log("genre: "+parts[0]+", song:"+parts[1]);
`
i get 

genre: #, song:genre

Comment: oops, make that `parts=location.hash.slice(1).split...`

Comment: Yes it  works! thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Test whether a particular index exists after splitting:

```
$(function(){
  var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1);
  var url_parts = hash.replace(/\/\s*$/,'').split('/');
  genre = url_parts.length >= 2 ? url_parts[1] : '';
  song = url_parts.length >= 3 ? url_parts[2] : '';
  console.log("result: "+url_parts);
 });
```